# Could i create a form to validate a budget?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

After the financial department calculate our sales budget, our salesman must to approve or change that budget.

We are thinking to use sharepoint to help them.

The idea is to read the data from the budget table and show it on a sharepoint and let the salesman change some amounts, after that it must update a table with the changes.

Is that possible? how could be the approach?

Kind Regards

Comment: Where is this 'budget table' stored?

Comment: On a sql database

Comment: So basically you just want SharePoint to be the user interface to allow a user to change values in the budget table stored in your SQL database? What version of SharePoint do you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a comprehensive guide on how to connect a SharePoint list to a SQL database using SharePoint Designer:

http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint-2013/archive/2013/01/07/how-to-create-external-list-including-database-from-sharepoint-designer-2013.aspx